# VTS few test cases give syntax error unexpected 'newline' and module gets reported as incomplete (inspite of test cases pass)

Tags: android-vts

/data/local/tmp/VtsHalBiometricsFaceV1_0TargetTest/VtsHalBiometricsFaceV1_0TargetTest.config[1]: syntax error: unexpected 'newline'
Total Tests       : 1
PASSED            : 1
FAILED            : 0
IMPORTANT: Some modules failed to run to completion, tests counts may be inaccurate.
============== End of Results ==============

Issue : Test case is passing but module is not getting reported as completed.

Issue seen with only Android 11 based VTS suites and works well with older android flavor VTS suites.
Environment of 18.04.2 LTS ubuntu and few modules inspite of passing the test cases it does not report a module pass (only for few modules) and shows it as Done=false in results report.

Logs indicate this kind of errors pointing to various .config files.

Any idea / suggestion what could be issue ?

Answer (score 0):

This was asked again in [syntax error: unexpected 'newline' in .config file in android vts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73050604/syntax-error-unexpected-newline-in-config-file-in-android-vts) and that got an answer that if you've modified the vts-tradefed file, then this error appears.

Additionally I noticed that even chmod changes can cause this problem to appear.

Comment: I have noticed that this is a strange problem and could not solve it with permission and re-download of VTS suite also. Tried everything even adb aspects. I suspect that this is due to some linux package compatibility issues. I have always solved it only by re-installing the linux and related python packages. Suspect that some package update might be triggering it.